Is it OK to drop a Box<T> as different type Box<S> in Rust?
In C, when calling free(), you need not to specify the memory block's size.
So in Rust, when calling drop() on a raw pointer, is it OK to pass the pointer as a different type?
Here is the example: I allocate the memory as type Full but free it as type Header. Is this OK?
struct Header {
    _state: i32,
}

#[repr(C)]
struct Full<T> {
    _header: Header,
    _body: T,
}

let full = Full {
    _header: Header {
        _state: 123,
    },
    _body: "hello, i'm a string",
};

let bb = Box::leak(Box::new(full));

// get ptr_t in type `*mut Full`
let ptr_t = bb as *mut Full<&'static str>;

// cast it into type `*mut Header`, to discard the generic <T>,
// then I can do something such as putting some `Full`s with different `T` in to one Vec.
// Since the `Header` is the first member in `Full`, this casting works fine.
let ptr_s = ptr_t as *mut Header;

///
// some business code to process `ptr_s` ...
///

// because we have lost the generic <T>, we can drop it as type `*mut Header` only
// Is it OK ???
unsafe { drop(Box::from_raw(ptr_s)); }

The <T> in Full<T> always has no special Drop implementation.

Rust also needs the size (and alignment) so this isn't going to work.

@drewtato what do you mean by "not work"? memory leak? does not free the body part in Full struct?

Prefer Box::into_raw() in this case to Box::leak().

Short answer: no it's not OK. As @Maxim Gritsenko's answer says, the drop implementation may do more than just release memory.
Moreover, all memory allocators need to know the size when freeing memory. The C std library went for convenience at the expense of performance, and malloc/free keep track of the size internally. This means that allocating a single char will take up 16 bytes of memory on 64-bit computers (1 byte for the char itself, 8 bytes for the size, and 7 bytes of padding so that the size of the next allocation can be aligned properly, 1500% overhead!).
Rust relies on the type system (*) to keep track of the allocated size at compile time so that the users can have the convenience and performance, but for this to work the user must not circumvent the type system and must always ensure that the type of dropped objects is the same as for the allocation.
(*) And the standard library for dynamic types (e.g. Vec and similar).

The allocator will always have to do some bookkeeping (for example pointers to the next/prev allocation), so allocations that have the exact same size as requested are unlikely. However, it is true that knowing the size/alignment allows more performant implementation for some allocators (but not all).

"The allocator will always have to do some bookkeeping" is not true in general (for example bump allocators) Also nothing forces an allocator to store that information inline (and thus changing the allocation size).

@cafce25 even bump allocators need to do some bookkeeping (even if it's only incrementing a pointer on allocation), and more so if they want to allow freeing memory.

Drop exist to free resources when an object is not needed any more. Resources here are not only memory, but can also mean OS sockets, file descriptors etc. These are freed by calling implementation of the Drop trait of a type.
So if you transmute your type into another and call its Drop implementation, in general you can get very unpredictable results, which include:

memory leaks
memory misalignment (access to memory belonging to other objects, e.g. security vulnerability)
leaking OS resources
double-freeing OS resources
many other very unpredictable things due to weird compiler optimizations based on assumption that your unsafe block doesn't do anything wrong when it does.

So, even if your two types have same mem::size_of it's quite unsound to drop one tape in place of other. And even if both types have no special Drop implementation, they can still have different memory alignment, which would cause broken memory allocation if you drop one instead of another.
Only if you are sure that

both types have the same memory size and
have the same memory alignment and
don't have special Drop implementation and
these will never change in the future, you might try doing it, but it is probably not a good idea.

You might be right to assume that the current default Rust allocator does not need mem::size_of to drop correct amount of memory since it is based on malloc which stores the allocated size of each block in the header of that block.
That being said, there are still 2 issues:

Rust program might not use default allocator, so you must keep that in mind if you develop a library and not an executable. An arbitrary allocator might rely on mem::size_of when releasing memory.

Even with default allocator, it will drop only the fields of the type being drop. So in your example _body field will not be released. It's not a problem in case T is &'static str, but it would lead to memory leak if T would be a String.



Thanks. I am sure that: 1) No, they do not have same size, but since free() in C does not need the size argument, so I want to know dose the size really matter? 2) yes, same alignment; 3) no special Drop; 4) no change in the future.

Rust's allocator interface gets the size on drop. Therefore, an implementation of this interface might rely on this size.

@SebastianRedl so it depends on the implementation, right? Thanks.

I've updated the answer with more details about the allocator.

Drop::drop being called is not a guarantee Rust makes (everything can be forgotten with std::mem::forget), so it's always ok to not call a particular drop, that might cause a resource leak, but it is not unsound in Rusts sense. I.e. the original types Drop implementation is irrelevant as long as the target types drop doesn't cause a double free or the likes.
